# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement') - Test Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to perform a test... I want to test my function in component.ts that receives an event through click, and this value passes to an output for the component dad.

The test code looks like this...

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { QuadradosComponent } from './quadrados.component';

describe('QuadradosComponent', () => {
  let component: QuadradosComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<QuadradosComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ QuadradosComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(QuadradosComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Deve emitir mensagem quando clicar na div', () => {

   const emitMessageSpy = spyOn(component.eventoOutput, 'emit')

   let divClick = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.casa')).nativeElement
   divClick.click()

   expect(emitMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled
  })
});
```

The component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { JogadasService } from 'src/app/services/jogadas.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-quadrados',
  templateUrl: './quadrados.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./quadrados.component.css']
})
export class QuadradosComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(public service: JogadasService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.emitirVitoria.subscribe(
      array => this.vitoria.push(...array)
    )
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('casa'))
  }
  vitoria: number[] =[];

  posicoes: number = 0;

  @Input() quadrados?: Array<number>;

  @Output() eventoOutput = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() index = new EventEmitter();


  eventoClick(evento: MouseEvent) {
    this.eventoOutput.emit(evento);
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('casa'))
  }

  pegaIndex(index: number) {
    this.posicoes = index;
    this.index.emit(this.posicoes);

  }

  vitoriaArray(modelo: number) {
   for(let i = 0; i< this.vitoria.length; i++) {
    if(this.vitoria[i] == modelo) {
      return this.vitoria[i]
    }
   }
  }
}
```

the component HTML:

```
<div class="centraliza">
  <div class="jogo-da-velha">
    <div class="linha">
      <div class="casa" *ngFor="let quadrado of quadrados, let i = index"
      (click)="pegaIndex(i)"
      [ngClass]="i == vitoriaArray(i)  ? 'casa-vencedor' : null"
      (click)="eventoClick($event)" ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Angular/Cli in version 15, I'm not getting a good understanding of the tests in Angular, thanks for the help.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question or try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: I made the changes

Answer (score 0):

`div.casa` is being rendered with an `*ngFor` and you have to make sure `quadrados` is a non empty array and not undefined.

Try this:

```
it('Deve emitir mensagem quando clicar na div', () => {

   const emitMessageSpy = spyOn(component.eventoOutput, 'emit')
   
   // Mock quadrados here
   component.quadrados = [{ } as any];
   
   // detect the changes here since the view model changed
   fixture.detectChanges();
   
   // the div should be there now
   let divClick = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.casa')).nativeElement
   divClick.click()

   expect(emitMessageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled
  })
```

Here is a good resource on learning testing with Angular: https://testing-angular.com/.